# Convert a macro name to pgfkey name

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, xparse, pgfkeys

Let's consider a macro name of the form `\first@second`. I would like to write a command that would convert the name of the macro to `pgfkey` name of the form `/first/second` so that the following approaches would be equivalent and have the same effect:

```
% This can change:
\newcommand{\macrotokey}[1]{% WHAT TO DO HERE? %}
\newcommand{\setviakey}[2]{\pgfkeys{#1 = #2}}
\newcommand{\setviamacro}[2]{\pgfkeys{\macrotokey{#1} = #2}}

% If possible I would like to have this syntax on the user side:
\setviakey{/A/B}{Hello}
\setviamacro{\A@B}{Hello}
```

I have no idea where to start to do such a trick.

Comment: \first@second is not normally a legal macro name.  It is possible to parse a macro name using \detokenize (\newcommand does it), but why?

Comment: I am in a zone where `\makeatletter` is "on" (to avoid the macro name being used elsewhere). How would you achieve that using `\detokenize`?

Comment: You should be able to run xstring parsing functions om detokenized csnames.  Removing the starting backslash may be tricky.

Comment: Seems you wish `\macrotokey` to transform the name of a control-sequence-token into a key-path. 1) Do you have patterns/rules in mind for distinguishing denotation of an absolute key path via control-sequence-token from denotation of a relative key path via control-sequence-token? 2) Under normal catcode-régime you can have names of keys that contain spaces but you need to do some catcode-trickery for causing TeX to take a space for a component of a name of a control sequence whiile tokenizing .tex-input. 3) How to handle keys whose names contains `@`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use `\macrotokey` within the argument of `\pgfkeys`, then `\macrotokey` needs to be fully expandable.

Expl3 comes along with a fully expandable routine `\cs_to_str:N` where the name of a control-sequence-token without leading escape character (usually backslash) is delivered by triggering two expansion-steps to `\cs_to_str:N`. With this routine you don't need to care for edge cases like `\escapechar` having value 32 or a negative value. (32 means that instead of a backslash a space is delivered as escape-character by things like `\string` or `\detokenize`. Negative value means that no escape-characteres are delivered at all.)

So let's use expl3 for defining a macro `\macrotokey{⟨argument⟩}` which triggers two expansion-steps on `\cs_to_str:N ⟨argument⟩` and then initiates a recursive loop `\__MyStuff_macrotokeyReplaceAtLoop:n` which checks whether the argument (still) contains `@` of category 12(other) and if so replaces the first of these `@` by `/` before calling itself again and if not so delivers the argument.

I would probably have named the thing `\cstokentokey` instead of `\macrotokey` because the meaning of the token that is to form the argument of `\macrotokey` is not relevant (except that it should not be an `\outer` token)—the argument being a control sequence token is sufficient. It does not even need to be defined.

If you uncomment `\exp_end:` and `\exp:w`, then the result of `\macrotokey`  is obtained by triggering exactly two expansion-steps on `\macrotokey`.
But for `\pgfkeys` this is not necessary as `\pgfkeys` triggers expansion of the tokens forming the key itself.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \MyStuff_GobbleTillAt:w #1@ {}
\cs_new:Npn \MyStuff_ReplaceAt:w #1@ { #1/ }
\cs_new:Nn \__MyStuff_macrotokeyReplaceAtLoop:n 
  {
    \tl_if_empty:oTF {\MyStuff_GobbleTillAt:w #1 @} 
                     { %\exp_end: 
                       #1
                       % If the name of the control-sequence-token begins with @, then it denotes an absolute path,
                       % otherwise the path is relative to what \pgfkeysdefaultpath was defined to via the /.cd-handler.
                       % If you do /#1  instead of #1, then every path is absolute and the names of
                       % control-sequence-tokens shall not begin with `@`.
                       % If you do  \pgfkeysdefaultpath #1  instead of #1, then every path is relative and the names of
                       % control-sequence-tokenss shall not begin with `@`.
                     } 
                     {
                       \exp_args:No \__MyStuff_macrotokeyReplaceAtLoop:n 
                                    {\MyStuff_ReplaceAt:w #1}
                     }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \macrotokey #1 
  { %\exp:w 
    \exp_args:NNo \exp_args:No 
                  \__MyStuff_macrotokeyReplaceAtLoop:n
                  { \cs_to_str:N #1 } 
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\setviamacro}[2]{\pgfkeys{\macrotokey{#1}={#2}}}
\newcommand{\setviakey}[2]{\pgfkeys{#1={#2}}}

\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{%
  %---------------------------------------------------------------
  % define the code to execute when encountering the key /A/B/C:
  %---------------------------------------------------------------
  /A/B/C/.code=\message{^^JKey /A/B/C's value in parentheses is: (#1)^^J},
  %---------------------------------------------------------------
  % Use the key /A/B/C :
  %---------------------------------------------------------------
  /A/B/C=Test 1: Absolute key provided,
  \macrotokey{\@A@B@C} = Test 1: Control sequence token denoting absolute key provided,
  /A/.cd,
  B/C=Test 2: Relative key provided,
  \macrotokey{\B@C} = Test 2: Control sequence token denoting relative key provided,
  /A/B/.cd,
  C=Test 3: Relative key provided,
  \macrotokey{\C} = Test 3: Control sequence token denoting relative key provided,
}

\setviakey{/A/B/C}{Test 4: Absolute key provided}
\setviamacro{\@A@B@C}{Test 4: Control sequence token denoting absolute key provided}

\stop
```

The following messages are delivered to the console:

```
Key /A/B/C's value in parentheses is: (Test 1: Absolute key provided)


Key /A/B/C's value in parentheses is: (Test 1: Control sequence token denoting 
absolute key provided)

Key /A/B/C's value in parentheses is: (Test 2: Relative key provided)


Key /A/B/C's value in parentheses is: (Test 2: Control sequence token denoting 
relative key provided)

Key /A/B/C's value in parentheses is: (Test 3: Relative key provided)


Key /A/B/C's value in parentheses is: (Test 3: Control sequence token denoting 
relative key provided)

Key /A/B/C's value in parentheses is: (Test 4: Absolute key provided)


Key /A/B/C's value in parentheses is: (Test 4: Control sequence token denoting 
absolute key provided)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `\setviamacro` is defined inside the expl syntax or can it be defined outside with `\newcommand`?

Comment: @Vincent It can be defined with `\newcommand` both inside and outside expl syntax. The reason why I defined it inside expl syntax is that I overlooked that expl syntax is not needed. ;-) I just edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the most robust version.

All macros don't use `@` in their name because then there would be a conflict between `@`<sub>11</sub> (a `@` with catcode 11, the one in the macro's name) and `@`<sub>12</sub> (the one that's produced by `\string`).

There are ways around it – there even was a Q about is recently which I can't find right now – but, honestly, I wouldn't use it that way anyway.

---

You could just define `\A@B` to expand to `/A/B` and use it as `\setviakey{\A@B}{…}` but I guess `\A@B` has another purpose in your use-case.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/A/B/.code=``#1''}
\begin{document}
\def\gobble#1{}

\def\macrotokeyatstripperstop{!stop!}%
\newcommand*\macrotokey[1]{%
  /\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\macrotokeyatstripper
  \expandafter\gobble\string#1@\macrotokeyatstripperstop
}%
\def\macrotokeyatstripper#1@#2{%
  #1\ifx\macrotokeyatstripperstop#2\expandafter\gobble\else
    /\expandafter\macrotokeyatstripper
  \fi#2}%

\newcommand{\setviakey}[2]{\pgfkeys{#1 = #2}}
\newcommand{\setviamacro}[2]{\pgfkeys{\macrotokey{#1} = #2}}

\setviakey{/A/B}{Hello}

\makeatletter
\setviamacro{\A@B}{Hello World}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```